# Can apps read other apps' RAM content on iOS?

Tags: mobile, ios, spyware

Can iOS apps read the RAM contents/cache/data of any other arbitrary app? Assume that the following conditions applies:

- The device is using only official iOS (no hacks or "jailbreaking")
- Obviously (due to the above conditions), all apps are downloaded and approved/signed by the App Store
- None of the apps are using exploits (or all known exploits have been patched) and programmer API restrictions are working as intended
- No other app on the device has been specifically set up to communicate with the app that wants to read the data

Context: preventing apps from snooping on each other. In particular, could a malicious app that somehow got through screening read RAM contents from every other app and harvest login cookies or personal information?

According to the [Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) it appears that apps are sandboxed to prevent this from happening; apps that want to share data have to be specifically set up for it (?).

Searching on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=can+ios+apps+read+other+apps+memory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) only turned up 2 Q&A's:

- [Can someone read a iOS class variable from outside the app?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115394/can-someone-read-a-ios-class-variable-from-outside-the-app)
- [Read data from other app's memory, is it challenging on a jailbroken device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740887/read-data-from-other-apps-memory-is-it-challenging-on-a-jailbroken-device)

both of which only discuss the topic in the context of using a developer kit or jailbroken devices, neither of which are on topic in this question.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. If the Apple docs say that things are sandboxed, then is your question if there is a known vulnerability that still makes it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible without the use of exploits. Even in Android, this is not possible.

Comment: I'd also like to add this is not possible in pretty much any OS without special permissions (debugger, root, etc) due to segmentation. This is where the `segfault` error comes from, meaning segmentation fault aka the program attempted to RW memory out of its bounds.

Comment: In Windows and Linux, this is possible when the thread is the same user or admin to the remote thread.

Comment: ‚No unless there is an exploit‘ means ‚Yes when you use an exploit‘ :)